# How to stop propagation of all events

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, stoppropagation

I wonder how to stop the propagation of all types of events when they reach a certain element.

I have thought

```
function stop(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
function stopEvents(el){
    var events = ['click', 'mousemove', ...];
    for(var i=0; i<events.length; ++i){
        el.addEventListener(events[i], stop, false);
    }
}
```

Is there a smarter way?

It seems that my code works, but I would like a code that doesn't require a list of all possible events.

> Because if I write a GreaseMonkey module which other people can use to
>   add content to pages, I don't want events generated inside that
>   content to trigger page's event listeners (assuming they don't use
>   capture). Actually I solved it using iframes, but the question remains
>   for academic purposes

Comment: That looks fine, does it work?

Comment: Listing out all the events might take a while. You should just automate that with JavaScript.

Comment: @Shawn31313 How can I get a list of all events?

Comment: @adeneo Because if I write a GreaseMonkey module which other people can use to add content to pages, I don't want events generated inside that content to trigger page's event listeners (assuming they don't use capture). Actually I solved it using iframes, but the question remains for academic purposes.

Comment: And at the same your GreaseMonkey script will kill all delegated event handlers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function stop(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}
function stopEvents(el){
    for(var key in window) {
        if (key.indexOf("on") == 0) {
            el.addEventListener(key.substr(2), stop, false);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you could get all of the events.

This could cause some issue though. For example, if you add another key into the `window` object that starts with `on`, it will also be considered an `"event"`.

You also have to consider that the `window` object is large.

I would just use your code. The full list of events would be:

### Google Chrome

```
["deviceorientation", "transitionend", "webkittransitionend", "webkitanimationstart", "webkitanimationiteration", "webkitanimationend", "search", "reset", "waiting", "volumechange", "unload", "timeupdate", "suspend", "submit", "storage", "stalled", "select", "seeking", "seeked", "scroll", "resize", "ratechange", "progress", "popstate", "playing", "play", "pause", "pageshow", "pagehide", "online", "offline", "mousewheel", "mouseup", "mouseover", "mouseout", "mousemove", "mousedown", "message", "loadstart", "loadedmetadata", "loadeddata", "load", "keyup", "keypress", "keydown", "invalid", "input", "hashchange", "focus", "error", "ended", "emptied", "durationchange", "drop", "dragstart", "dragover", "dragleave", "dragenter", "dragend", "drag", "dblclick", "contextmenu", "click", "change", "canplaythrough", "canplay", "blur", "beforeunload", "abort"]
```

### FireFox

```
["SearchSubmit", "mouseenter", "mouseleave", "afterprint", "beforeprint", "beforeunload", "hashchange", "message", "offline", "online", "popstate", "pagehide", "pageshow", "resize", "unload", "devicemotion", "deviceorientation", "deviceproximity", "userproximity", "devicelight", "abort", "blur", "canplay", "canplaythrough", "change", "click", "contextmenu", "dblclick", "drag", "dragend", "dragenter", "dragleave", "dragover", "dragstart", "drop", "durationchange", "emptied", "ended", "error", "focus", "input", "invalid", "keydown", "keypress", "keyup", "load", "loadeddata", "loadedmetadata", "loadstart", "mousedown", "mousemove", "mouseout", "mouseover", "mouseup", "mozfullscreenchange", "mozfullscreenerror", "mozpointerlockchange", "mozpointerlockerror", "pause", "play", "playing", "progress", "ratechange", "reset", "scroll", "seeked", "seeking", "select", "show", "stalled", "submit", "suspend", "timeupdate", "volumechange", "waiting", "wheel", "copy", "cut", "paste", "beforescriptexecute", "afterscriptexecute"]
```

Comment: Did you try that? Does the `document` hold a list of events, I was under the impression you'd get stuff like `.appendChild`, `.write` etc. back, i.e. the methods accessible on the document level ?

Comment: It seems to grab the functions named on* as well.

Comment: @mvw Thats true. And i'm sorry, i need to update my code. I need to use window to get all the events.

Comment: @adeneo the document object does hold a few events like onclick, oninput...but the window object contains the full list.

Comment: Now you're passing `onclick` to addEventListener(), which expects just `click` as the events name ?

Comment: I guess that it should be `el.addEventListener(key.substring(2), stop, false);`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, just fixed that. But in general this isn't a very efficient way because of the size of the `window` object. So is it smarter? Not really. Easier? Yes.

Comment: I don't really use `el.addEventListener` a lot so I didn't know if you use the `on` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a chance for `css` on disabled areas?

```
pointer-events : none;
```

Comment: That's an interesting CSS property which I didn't know. I've tried `*{pointer-events:none}
#el, #el *{pointer-events:auto}` but doesn't work because with `pointer-events:none` "*the element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events **will trigger event listeners on this parent** element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.*" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events